# Adding an Image to a Silverlight Application Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'm currently doing an unpaid, part time internship at a public school district.  I've been assigned a project to build a webpage that cleans up the desktop for elementary school images (Installs of OS (Windows 7) with custom default applications and settings) in the district.  The current images have numerous shortcuts to websites that the students use because these students don't know how to use browsers yet.

Instead of having a separate shortcut for each website, all images in the district will receive a new shortcut to the website I am building.  It organizes hyperlink images by school. (All, Elementary, Middle, High) This reduces desktop clutter by using one shortcut to bring up clear and easy to use links for anyone in the district.  It also includes staff links, such as for Email login, Helpdesk Requests, etc.

Background: I work mostly with Java, but I have experience with .NET Forms Programming.  I have never built a web-hosted application before and am trying to learn to use Silverlight because this district is an all Microsoft district and Java gives the IT department too many issues.

I could add the images by hand on the page designer or through xaml, but then we run into a problem: I'm the only one in the district with "significant" (more than a 3 hour intro course) programming experience.  For the page to maintain functionality after I leave this May, I am creating a sister application that allows users to easily edit markup files that store information about each set of links.  This means that the primary web application needs to read these files and create the links itself.  The problem I've encountered is in making images appear on the layout root.

Instead of adding them directly to the root, I created a `Canvas` in xaml that will host all the images and links.  This `Canvas` is named "Root" to aid in confusion.  The code I am using to attempt to add a test image is below.

```
        Image imagy = new Image
        {
            Width = Height = 200,
            Name = "imagy",
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Links Workspace\\GC Web Links\\District Links\\District Links\\src\\Images\\test.png")),
        };

        Root.Children.Add(imagy);
        Canvas.SetLeft(imagy, 100.0);
        Canvas.SetTop(imagy, 100.0);
```

The path is correct, however when built and loaded, the image is not present.  The code is being executed without throwing any exceptions.  I've also tried initializing the image object and setting the properties afterwards, and tried to add it without changing any property but the source and I still don't see the image.  Is it initializing invisible, is it adding in an off-screen location, is it loading behind the layout root?  At this point I'm not sure what the issue could be which is why I am here.  I cannot see a difference between the code I am using and the code most people have submitted as solutions to other problems concerning this on WPF applications.

Comment: Are  you trying to access that image file on the HDD from a web-browser hosting a Silverlight plug-in?

Comment: The HDD belongs to the server I am building and will be hosting the application on.  Does the URI in a 
Silverlight app look at the computer running it or the server it is hosted on?

Comment: Silverlight is client-side technology. It is run on the client, not the server. It does not work like server pages (ASP for example). The application runs on the client machine, you can not (directly) access files on the server. You need to host those files in a way accessible from the Silverlight client, via http for instance.

Comment: That is something I didn't know!  Thank you very much, I will try the code with an http address and see what I get.